# How to adjust data in spinner if data's length is too long?

Tags: android, spinner

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> arr_adapt ;

str_eye_cat = "Select^"+str_eye_cat;
str_arr = fun.split(str_eye_cat.trim(), "^");
arr_adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str_arr);
arr_adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spn_eye_cat.setAdapter(arr_adapt);
```

I have used above code....

But I want to increase the size of the list in the spinner so that user can see what he is selecting.

Comment: Want to finish the sentence in your title?

Comment: know please suggest something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...what I *think* you want is to make the spinner either wider or more narrow so that the things in it display correctly? If that's what you want, than the code you need is in the XML file, where make the spinner. The android:layout_width is what you'd need.

If you need to increase the size of the adapter that *makes* the list, then that's a different story. What you can do is make a string array in the strings.xml file in the values directory, like this:

```
<string-array name="EU_types">
    <item>Units</item>
    <item>%</item>
    <item>BBLS</item>
    <item>BPD</item>
    <item>CFM</item>
    <item>DegC</item>
</string-array>
```

This array can pretty much hold as much as you want it to, but the values have to be all preset like this. If you want to pull the values dynamically from a database, then that's a whole other story. Anyways, you can reference this array like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.EU_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Then you simply use that to fill your spinner like this:

`Spinner yourspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_SPINNER);
yourspinner.setAdapter(adapter2);`

Hopefully one of those will be useful to you.

Comment: i don't want to initialize adapter through xml dataset... but i am generating it through string[] array..

Comment: alright then. based on your code...you have a string array named AgencyListArray? Unless you yourself specifically defined exactly how many items will be in the array, they can hold any number of records. to add to it you just use AgencyListArray.add(String) or .add(int index, String). You didn't include your code for it, but the line where you created your list array should look like this: ArrayList<String> AgencyListArray= new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: i am new in android... so if you tell what % will do if i add it in array.... as you have suggested something like this... <item>%</item>

Comment: That is literally a % sign. See, I pulled that code from a project I worked on where someone could select what units they were working with, generic units, %, BBLS, BPD, CFM, or DegC. If you want the % in an array, than you would just pass it in like everything else. I hope that is what you were asking for.